# How to concatenate row values, based on another row values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Imagine I have a table like this:

[Table exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTNVu.png)

I want to concatenate 1st row values, if the cell on respective column on the 2nd row has value Yes.

I.e. the result should be: (Sample_1,Sample_4,Sample_5).

I've been trying to use: `=TEXTJOIN(","; TRUE; IF(2:2 = "Yes"; 1:1; ""))` But it obviously does not work, as range cannot be equal to value.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Your formula is fine, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to confirm. If one has ExcelO365 CSE is not needed, also you can use `FILTER()` in such case > `=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(1:1,2:2="Yes"))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:G2="yes",B1:G1,""))
```

[image]

As you see this is in the Excel web app using US Locale for the separator.
*(the web app does not require array-entry.)*